# Deshabilitar botón mediante ng-form y ng-class

Tags: angularjs

[image: Web]
Tengo este código que implementé para deshabilitar el poder hacer clic en un botón

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="funUpdate(message); showDetails = ! showDetails" ng-class="{ 'disabled': messageForm_{{$index}}.$invalid}" ><span class="fa fa-check" ></span></a>
```

El cual corresponde para deshabilitar el botón verde en caso de que el campo message.mensaje este vacío:

```
<tr ng-form="messageForm_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="message in modelSearchResponse.messages track by message.id">
                <td class="text-center col-md-2">
                    <span ng-class="{ 'hidden': showDetails }">{{message.mensaje}}</span>
                    <input ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }" type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="message.mensaje">
                </td>
```

Como pueden apreciar, tuve que agregarle al campo de mensaje la primer línea, que contiene "ng-form" y "ng-repeat"

Lo que quiero saber es qué parte del código debería de cambiar/agregar para añadir otra funcionalidad más, y que sea la de deshabilitar el botón en caso de que mi primer campo esté vacío (en este caso, el primer campo que corresponde donde está el asterisco "*", ver imagen)

```
<tr ng-form="messageCForm_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="message in modelSearchResponse.messages track by message.id">
```

antes de mi primer campo:

```
<tr ng-form="messageCForm_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="message in modelSearchResponse.messages track by message.id">
                <td class="text-center col-md-2">
                    <span ng-class="{ 'hidden': showDetails }">{{message.codigo}}</span>
                    <input code ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }" type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="message.codigo">
                </td>
```

Probé cambiando nombres y no logro hacer que funcione. No logro poder implementarlo.

Comment: Hola que versión de angular usas? Angularjs y Angular se refieren a versiones muy diferentes. AngularJs es para AngularJS 1.x y Angular es para las versiones a partir de la 2.

Comment: No sabía. AngularJS.

Comment: No se si funcione con AngularJs.  `[disabled]="message.lenght<1"`. En caso de que estés usando el binding en dos vias. Pero desconozco completamente AngularJS.

Comment: Puede que esto te funcione. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Si, ya he probado con eso y funciona, sucede que quiero mantener la estructura de código, usando el ng-form. Muchas gracias igual.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma para validar tus formularios y deshabilitar botones o elementos del DOM dependiendo de dicho formulario, es utilizar las características propias de AngularJS como son **[estas](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)**, con las cuales puedes corroborar si se toco o no un input, si esta vacío, entre otras.

Dicho esto, sólo falta asignarle un nombre a cada elemento de tu DOM y especificar que son requeridos (**[ngRequired](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)**) de la siguiente forma.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.current = {};
  $scope.options = [
    { name: 'Uno', value: '1'},
    { name: 'Dos', value: '2'},
    { name: 'Tres', value: '3'}
  ]
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form name="mainForm" class="container mt-4" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" novalidate>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control" ng-model="current.input1" ng-required="true">
        </td>        
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="select" ng-model="current.select" ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in options | orderBy: 'name'" ng-required="true">
            <option value="">Default</option>
          </select>
        </td>        
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="input2" class="form-control" ng-model="current.input2" ng-required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:white"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!mainForm.$valid"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:white"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas =)

Comment: No creo que sea lo que necesito... quiero hacerlo de la misma manera que lo hice, con el ng-form y el ng-class. Sin necesidad de agregar un método. Más o menos la misma estructura que ya hice

Comment: Para que entiendas un poco, `ngForm` es muy útil cuando necesitas validar objetos del **DOM** por separado, cosa que para tu caso no aplica porque tú necesitas validar varios elementos dentro de un mismo formulario, por eso utilice el tag `form` en desmedro de _ng-form_; `ng-class` podrías utilizarlo para marcar el _input_ que no cumple cierta condición con algún estilo particular, cosa que se puede realizar de igual forma en el código que propuse. Y en cuanto al método que hablas... **no estoy utilizando ninguno..**